# Spark Scala function calling

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The requirement is as below:

```scala
val value = Array["id","sd","cd"]  -- List of columns 
val cols_list = Array["cd","id","tm","no","in","ts","nm"] -  -- List of columns
```

abcd is schema name. Need columns which are in value and the columns in cols_list which are not in value.

```scala
val alter = df.select(value + ("abcd." + x.toUpperCase() for x <- cols_list if x.toUpperCase() not in value)).where(df.status =="ALERT")
```

The error is it not able read  x.
The requirement is dataframe with select condition and for loop with not in and action. Any ideas/Suggestions please.

I have tried like below
              val diff_cols = value diff cols_list  --- Looks like this is not good idea.

```
         val alter = df.select(value + ("abcd." + diff_cols).where(df.status 
           =="ALERT")
```

but the issue i see now is instead of columns [Ljava.lang.String;@6cc9bbea is passing and it's failing.

Please suggest if anyone have any other solutions?

Comment: you need the provide sample data to reproduce the issue.I feel you have syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below code.

In spark you can access columns without schema name.

```
scala> val value = Array("id","sd","cd")
value: Array[String] = Array(id, sd, cd)

scala> val cols_list = Array("cd","id","tm","no","in","ts","nm")
cols_list: Array[String] = Array(cd, id, tm, no, in, ts, nm)

scala> val columns = value ++ cols_list.diff(value)
columns: Array[String] = Array(id, sd, cd, tm, no, in, ts, nm)

scala> val schema = "abcd"
schema: String = abcd

scala> columns.map(column => s"${schema}.${column}") // This step is not required, in spark you can access columns without schema name. if you still want you can use like this.
res14: Array[String] = Array(abcd.id, abcd.sd, abcd.cd, abcd.tm, abcd.no, abcd.in, abcd.ts, abcd.nm)

scala> df.select(columns.head,columns.tail:_*).where($"status" === "ALERT")
```

Comment: you are not accepting any answers given for all your questions. please do that to close thread.

Comment: I upvoted it thinking it would work. The person who asked should accept.